# vb.net print multiple pages

Tags: vb.net, loops, printing

my problem here is how to print it on multiple pages, page counts are depends on the user input on textbox9. please help me. thanks

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = New System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("Paper Size Name", 300, 300)
    Dim CT As Date = Now ' Use of Now.
    TextBox17.Text = (CT.ToShortDateString)
    Dim font1 As New Font("arial", 6, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim font2 As New Font("arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim myBitmap As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(filename:="C:\Users\jtapellido\Desktop\sticker pictures\slogo1.png")

    Dim index As Integer = 1

    Do
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image:=myBitmap, point:=New Point(70, 20))
        e.Graphics.DrawString("QUARANTINE", font2, Brushes.Black, 70, 40)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("MATERIAL NAME:_________________________________", font1, Brushes.Black, 70, 60)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("QC No:_____________", font1, Brushes.Black, 70, 80)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("LOT No:____________", font1, Brushes.Black, 70, 100)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("DATE RECEIVED:______________", font1, Brushes.Black, 170, 80)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("EXPIRATION DATE:____________", font1, Brushes.Black, 170, 100)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("QUANTITY:____________", font1, Brushes.Black, 70, 120)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("VENDOR/MANUFATURER:", font1, Brushes.Black, 70, 140)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("________________________________________________", font1, Brushes.Black, 70, 160)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("CONTAINER No:________________OF________________", font1, Brushes.Black, 70, 180)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("STORAGE:_______________________________________", font1, Brushes.Black, 70, 200)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("REMARKS:_______________________________________", font1, Brushes.Black, 70, 220)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("PREPARED BY/DATE:", font1, Brushes.Black, 70, 240)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("CHECKED BY/DATE:", font1, Brushes.Black, 190, 240)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("____________________", font1, Brushes.Black, 70, 255)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("____________________", font1, Brushes.Black, 190, 255)

        e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox1.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 145, 58)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox2.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 110, 78)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox3.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 110, 98)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox4.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 255, 78)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox5.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 255, 98)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox6.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 120, 118)
        'e.Graphics.DrawString("VENDOR/MANUFATURER:", font1, Brushes.Black, 10, 120)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox7.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 70, 158)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(index, font1, Brushes.Black, 170, 178)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox9.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 255, 178)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox11.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 120, 198)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox12.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 120, 218)
        'e.Graphics.DrawString("PREPARED BY/DATE:", font1, Brushes.Black, 10, 220)
        'e.Graphics.DrawString("CHECKED BY/DATE:", font1, Brushes.Black, 120, 220)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox15.Text + " " + TextBox17.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 70, 253)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ComboBox2.Text + " " + TextBox17.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 190, 253)
        'e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, e.MarginBounds)
        index += 1
    Loop Until index > TextBox9.text
End Sub
```

Comment: Please use the preview provided for the intended purpose, i.e. look at your question and don't submit it if the formatting is a mess.

Comment: Turn on option strict, then fix the errors that appear. Supect your problem will be you are comparing a string to a integer _Loop Until index > TextBox9.text_

Comment: @Hursey, there probably should not be a loop at all, if the intent is to print one page per iteration. Any time you want to print multiple pages, you MUST be using `e.HasMorePages`, which is not happening here. That certainly doesn't mean that `Option Strict On` is not a good idea though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic for printing multiple pages is pretty simple. The `PrintPage` event handler does just what the name suggests, i.e. it prints a page. At the end of the method, you set `e.HasMorePages` to `True` if there are more pages to print and that's it. The event will be raised again and another page printed.

It's up to you to provide logic at the start of the method to determine what page you're printing and at the end to determine whether there are more pages to print. Because you need to remember a state between calls to that method, you'll likely store the relevant data in one or more fields.

Here is an example of printing record from a list, ten to a page:

```vb
Private allData As New List(Of String)
Private dataToPrint As Queue(Of String)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Start printing.
    PrintDocument1.Print()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_BeginPrint(sender As Object, e As PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.BeginPrint
    'Create a new queue containing all the current data.
    dataToPrint = New Queue(Of String)(allData)
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    'Print a maximum of 10 records.
    For i = 1 To Math.Min(dataToPrint.Count, 10)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(dataToPrint.Dequeue(),
                              Font,
                              Brushes.Black,
                              25,
                              i * 25)
    Next

    'Keep printing if and only if there are more records to print.
    e.HasMorePages = (dataToPrint.Count > 0)
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_EndPrint(sender As Object, e As PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.EndPrint
    dataToPrint = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you wanted to print a specific number of pages based on the contents of a `TextBox` then you might convert that contents to an `Integer` and assign that to a field at the start. You could then decrement that variable at the end of the `PrintPage` event handler and print another page if and only if that counter is greater than zero.

Comment: Hi John Thankyou for your answer.  but i have small favor to ask can you do it on my example above?

Comment: @JomarApellido, I don't know what you want to print on each page because you haven't explained it. There's also a lot of code there that I don't feel inclined to reproduce. You're supposed to provide a minimal example that demonstrates your issue. How about you put some thought into the principle that I have demonstrated here and make an effort to apply it to your scenario, then fully explain any specific issues you encounter in doing so, if any?